# Why all major browsers not support HTML5 New Input Types like color, date and HTML5 New Form Elements

Tags: html

I am learning HTML5.
I saw that HTML5 new input types like color, date, datetime-local, range, number, month, etc. are not working in all browsers. Is their any reason for this?

And input type `tel` is also not working in any browser. How can I test it?
I am using Windows 7. Is it working on Mac?
I am learning from site [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp).
One thing that the new coming versions of popular browsers will support this types or not?

Same thing happens for HTML5 new Form elements like `datalist`, `keygen`, `output` these 3 elements not supported by any versions of Internet Explorer.

Should we use these elements for our requirements or not?

Comment: Because developers need time to implement them.

Comment: It should be implemented before release or not?

Comment: Means they do not show these elements before their completion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a web application you have to consider the compatibility of that application with all the currently prominent browsers as many people might be using the applications with their own personal choice of browsers.

Even if all these features are available in the latest browsers we will have to consider the browser compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

html5 is great, but as you say is not quite there. But not be discourage, embrace it, because is the next step in evolution for the markup. Right now there's options for cross browser issues, like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), that gives you the opportunity of "Taking advantage of cool new web technologies ..., until you have to support browsers that lag behind"