# Why is HTML5 input type datetime removed from browsers already supporting it?

Tags: html, datetime, html-input, browser-support

I was wondering why all browsers, like Chrome versions higher than 26, which had support in the past for the input `datetime` removed it?

This sounds like a duplicate of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410883/why-all-major-browsers-not-support-html5-new-input-types-like-color-date-and-htm), but that one is quite aged.

It looks like the HTML WG prefers `datetime-local` ([w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime-local.html)) above `datetime` ([w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime.html)), but why?

See [this](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-datetime-element/form-datetime-local-element.html) for feature development timeline.

**What others say:**

According to [mobilexweb.com](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review) it was deprecated in iOS 'because it looks too much like the datetime input type'.

> Following Google Chrome, now Safari on iOS doesn’t support the
>   datetime input type anymore and it will fallback to text. This type
>   was deprecated in the standard in favor of datetime-local or using two
>   inputs, date and time for the same purpose. The problem is that
>   datetime was compatible with iOS from version 5.0 to 6.1; if you are
>   using it, be careful!

**What is the difference?**

Where `datetime-local` contains only a date and time element, `datetime` also contains the time zone. This is useful since you might want to act differently when the client's time zone is different from the server's one.

**Why does this matter?**

> What if the web page asks: when do you want me to call you, and the user selects 'tomorrow, 3pm', when do you need to call him back? tomorrow 3pm UTC or CET?

Comment: HTML5 is still a "candidate recommendation".  It's not final yet.  That's probably why things keep changing.

Comment: True, but as far as I can see the recommendation has not changed, so this seems to be a browser vendor's choice.

Comment: I guess you'll have to find an external library or make it yourself...

Comment: There's some useful information at [Webmasters.SE - Is datetime-local removed from HTML 5.1?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59284/is-datetime-local-removed-from-html-5-1) on the future of `date`, `time`, `datetime`, and `datetime-local`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is browser vendors losing faith in the standard being approved, therefore removing the implementation from their code.

To support this thought: W3C just removed both `datetime` and `datetime-local` from their working draft.

Browser vendors will eventually drop support of both of them.

According to [html5test](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-datetime-element.html) most of the current browsers removed support of both of the input types.

The latest development:

- The `datetime-local` is back on the draft;
- The newer specs page doesn't show `datetime`, but it does show [`datetime-local`](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/input). It does sound like it is back on the map and going to be supported again!

Also take notice of this related post on Webmasters.SE: [Is datetime-local removed from HTML 5.1?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59284/is-datetime-local-removed-from-html-5-1).

Comment: Who defines standard if not they(developers of IE.Chrome, Firefox), why they delete perfectly fine things from browser?

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It worked. It worked well. I need it. Why remove it?

Comment: @Yoda: It seems that `datetime-local` at least is back on the roadmap.

Comment: Yes, the sad thing is that we begin to see discrepancies between the two working groups, W3C ([W3C version of input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)) and WHATWG ([WHATWG version of input](https://developers.whatwg.org/the-input-element.html#the-input-element)). I feared this would happen some day...

Comment: I love how this problem is still not solved over 25 years after the web was created. Pretty much sums up the software industry as a whole IMO.

Comment: Firefox is still not supporting `datetime-local`! Why should I use a feature which only works on Chrome?!

Comment: datetime-local does not have a timezone though, so I am guessing it whats the original type="datetime" was?

Answer (score 9):

Source http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

> "The following features are at risk and may be removed due to lack of implementation.
>  ..<input type=datetime>.."