# Twitter Bootstrap Form Input Overflow on Chrome Only

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I'm having a weird problem where `datetime-local` inputs overflow their boundaries on Chrome (tested so far on Chrome 35 x64 for Linux), but don't on Firefox (29.0). Here's a screenshot of what happens in Chrome:

[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI0j8.png)

And here's what it looks like in Firefox:

[firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA1ab.png)

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="filter-panel" class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="list-group">
                     <!-- Filter by time -->
                         <li class="list-group-item">
                             <h4>Filter by Time</h4>
                             <div class="input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon">Oldest</span>
                                 <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="log-filter-early-time">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Newest</span>
                                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="log-filter-late-time">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- more li elements -->
```

There isn't any css except the twitter bootstrap affecting it. I'm using the most recent version (downloaded a few days ago).

How can I make it so that the input fields are constrained in their div? I do want them to take the whole width, but nothing more. Also, is it possible to get the spans with .input-group-addon to be the same width without giving them fixed, pixel-unit-ed values? I tried assigning them the same width as a percent but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with full code? You should probably create a parent div as a wrapper, and use that to control inner divs by percentage.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/RdMXV/

Comment: interesting, one thing i see already is the way timestamps are displayed are different between the 2 browsers.. this is interesting, and date/time selector not working for me on firefox

Comment: Do you mean that the I should use a div around the `.input-group` ones, and give those a width of 100%?

Comment: So perhaps it would be better to use a different input type entirely, if this one is so inconsistent across browsers.

Comment: It appears that changing from `datetime-local` to `datetime` fixed the issue in chrome. I'm not sure why that fixed it, but it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` is no longer supported in firefox when you put datetime-local it seems to work

[here is a discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263515/why-is-html5-input-type-datetime-removed-from-browsers-already-supporting-it)

in chrome the `datetime-local` which is [supported](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime) has a min width regardless of the container div so appears to be broken but its not .. if you want the datetime-local input you have to have enough space in the container

http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-datetime-local-element.html

Comment: That's unfortunate. I don't really want to do browser detection for something like this. Do you have a suggestion other than more room (I really can't add space to the sidebar, the rest of the content is the whole point of the page)?