# Optional time in <input type="datetime-local" required>

Tags: html, datetime, input, datetime-local

It is possible to set a default value for the time only or make the time optional for a datetime-local input (see this article as reference: [MDN web-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)):

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="2017-06-01T08:30" required/>
```

How can I preload only the time or make the time, but not the date optional, e. g.:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="YYYY-MM-DDT12:05" required/>
```

This should look something like this:
[image: only time is set]

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "no, unfortunately this is not possible". You might be able to "fake" it with a regular text input and some trickery, but would certainly involve some JS on the validation side of things.

Comment: I am not sure if this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323854/setting-default-time-value-for-datetime-local) will assist in answering your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to do it in a single `datetime` input, but you can set default value for time input, so use an empty `date` input and a `time` input with default value, then use some CSS to make them like they are one input.

```css
#time{
  border-left:0px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
#time{
  border-left:0px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
#date{
  border-right:0px;
}
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" required id="date">
<input type="time" required value="07:30:00" id="time">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question well, the above-pointing time can not be archived.

The `datatime-local` attribute value is a string representing a local date and time. Regarding [RFC3339](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/references.html#refsRFC3339) data and time, the return value should be data and time representation.

As a solution we can define the time inside a `<time>` HTML tag. The `<time>` HTML Tag is an HTML5 element in the Html file that indicates either a timestamp on a 24-hour clock or a date in the calendar.

Ex:

```html
<p>The birthday of John is on <time datetime="2022-02-28">next Sunday</time>.</p>
```

```html
<p>I've finally uploaded my first ever vlog <time datetime="2022-02-17T06:00-08:00">6am last Tuesday</time>.</p>
```

See Time Refernce W3Schools [HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp)