# AngularJS Format date in read only field

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble formatting a date in a read-only field using AngularJS.  This is my html code -

```
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2">Date Last Login:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="datetime" name="dateLastLogin" class="form-control" data-ng-model="loginDate" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried to format it using this code in my controller -

```
$scope.$watch('vm.account.dateLastLogin', function(newValue) {
    $scope.loginDate = $filter('date')(newValue, 'MM/DD/yyyy');
});
```

Putting a break point in the controller, I see the function being called but nothing is displayed.

If I leave my html like this -

```
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2">Date Last Login:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" name="dateLastLogin" class="form-control" data-ng-model="vm.account.dateLastLogin" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I get a displayed value that includes the date and time but not formatted as I need it.  What am I missing?

Comment: You tried to input type="date"?

Comment: Also, MM/DD/yyyy isn't a valid pattern (or at least, it won't do what you want). And the documentation of the input of type date, datetime-local, etc. says: *The model must always be a Date object, otherwise Angular will throw an error.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263999/3199927) answer, the W3C removed the `datetime` input type from the HTML5 Specification.  `date` and `datetime-local` are still valid.

In your example, throw out the formatting filter and simply use the `ng-model="vm.account.dateLastLogin"` on a valid `date` input, like:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="vm.account.dateLastLogin" />
```

or

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="vm.account.dateLastLogin" />
```

These date formats are formatted correctly to the client browsers locale.

Or, if you actually just want it in some text field, put the filter directly in the `ng-model` but still use a valid `Date` object, like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.account.dateLastLogin | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" readonly />
```

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/pesufolevo/1/edit?html,js,output) for some examples

Comment: Putting a filter in the ng-model produce an error on the page (it does work, but with error), do you know why?
"runner-3.35.12.min.js:1 Error: [ngModel:nonassign]..."