# Datetime-local type

Tags: html, datetime, browser

I'm using an input `type="datetime-local"`, but it works just in the Chrome browser, & not for the Firefox one.. is there any simple idea to solve this please?

Comment: check your firefox version.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263515/why-is-html5-input-type-datetime-removed-from-browsers-already-supporting-it