# Input type=time showing wrong timezone

Tags: javascript, html

When using `<input type="time">` and setting the time with `valueAsDate` the browser displays the time in GMT instead of local time, is there any way to change this behavior? I want the browser to display the local time.

If you're not on GMT time than you should see that the hour in the input is different the in the `p` element

(I tried this in Chrome and Firefox)

```js
let date = new Date;
document.querySelector("input").valueAsDate = date;
document.querySelector("p").innerText = date;
```

```html
<input type="time">
<p></p>
```

Comment: I am in Central Time Zone and I do see a different time (10:27:17.933 PM) in input field and a different time (Tue Dec 03 2019 16:27:17 GMT--0600 Central Standard Time) in the p element.

Comment: So basically you just want to get the current timezone a user is in. This might not be the answer you want, but have you thought of using Moment's Timezone? Moment has saved me from a lot of headache with date and time issues. Note: I'm in PST so I'm seeing what you are saying I should see.

Comment: [html5-date-input-field-and-valueasdate-timezone-gotchas](https://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/html5-date-input-field-and-valueasdate-timezone-gotcha-3/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to set and get HTMLInputElement.valueAsDate using local Dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032953/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-and-get-htmlinputelement-valueasdate-using-local)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.toLocaleString` can help out here:

```js
let date = new Date;
document.querySelector("input").value = date.toLocaleString("sv-SE", {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit"
});
document.querySelector("p").innerText = date;
```

```html
<input type="time">
<p></p>
```

I wrote up a little article about this problem [on dev.to](https://dev.to/mendyberger/input-and-js-dates-2lhc).

Answer (score 1):

To get the local time you should create `date` object and set hours and minutes in input field.Check my solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
 
    setInterval(updateTime,1000);
    
    function updateTime(){
        //create date instance to get now time 
        var date = new Date();
        hours = date.getHours();
        minutes = date.getMinutes();
        seconds = date.getSeconds();
        
        //add extra zero if the minutes is less than 2 digits
        if(hours < 10){
          hours = '0' + hours;
        }

        //add extra zero if the minutes is less than 2 digits
        if(minutes < 10){
          minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
      
        $('input[type="time"]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr({'value': hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds});
        });
      
      //document.getElementById("myTime").value = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
      
    }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTime" type='time'/>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. According the HTML spec for :

> The algorithm to convert a Date object to a string, given a Date object input, is as follows: Return a valid time string that represents the UTC time component that is represented by input.

If you want to display a localized time string, you should try converting to a string (see [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)) first or using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Than whats the point of having `valueAsDate`? if the date it sets and returns are never what you need (unless your on GMT)