# Date Formatting in Input

Tags: javascript, html

The value attribute of input tag only accepts the YYYY-mm-dd format

```
<input type="date" value="YYYY-mm-dd">
```

In my app the user birth date is returned in the format: Jan 1, 1999

If I do this nothing happens:

```
<input type="date" value="Jan 1, 1999">
```

So how can I display the user birth date if the format I have is different, maybe write a javascript function that returns the correct format but then the problem is how do you stick that function to an attribute

Comment: How are you setting the value attribute now?

Comment: You can refer to this answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?rq=1

Comment: @HereticMonkey `<input type="date" value={{ user.profile.birth_date }}>`

Comment: `{{ user.profile.birth_date }}` returns Jan 1, 1999

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information, and also include what framework/library you're using (React, Angular, etc.). Add the tag for it as well.

Comment: Date displayed in the `date` type `input` depends on the locale of the user's browser but the parsed value of the date is always in the format: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

If you have a date string in a different format, you need to convert it to the valid format, i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate the string you get to a `input type=date`'s value with vanilla Javascript.

Demo:

```html
<label> click to set value
  <input type="text" value="Jan 1, 1999 " onfocus="document.querySelector('#date').valueAsDate = new Date(new Date(this.value).setDate(new Date(this.value).getDate() + 1))" />
</label>
<label>
Input date:
<input id="date" type="date" value="0"> 
</label>
```

You will happy to read about `.valueAsDate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032953/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-and-get-htmlinputelement-valueasdate-using-local),

And since it get the day before, i fixed it with setting the date to the day after - You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date).

Answer (score 0):

You can add Jquery Datepicker,

[Jquery Datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

In this you can able to set the which type of format you want

[Jquery Datepicker format](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html)