# HTML datetime-local change event?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to handle "datetime-selection" event with `<input type='datetime-local'>` control?

onchange, onselect and oninput does not work for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. What does "does not work for me" mean exactly?

Comment: onchange triggers when the field is completely filled

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks like a bug in the browser, because `onchange` and `onselect` are global for all HTML elements according to the specification here: [https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html)

Comment: Wow. Thanks!!! It works (onchange triggers when the field is completely filled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In chrome) the onchange event triggers when the field is completely filled

Also have a read of [Why is HTML5 input type datetime removed from browsers already supporting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263515/why-is-html5-input-type-datetime-removed-from-browsers-already-supporting-it)

Answer (score 3):

Since `onchange` does not occur until after the field is fully filled in I ended up doing an `onselect` that sends `new Date()` to the `onchange` handler if the field does not yet have a value. This eliminates the false sense of a value being set (perhaps on a backing object) on the field before the time part of dateime-local is set.

Comment: An example would have been nice here.