# set state in a function not working - reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATE: I have logged three lines of code, before sending the data to updateEvent function containing the endpoint. The following is the logs:

> the new event date is  2019-01-01T01:00:00.000
>
> the new SET event date is:  2019-01-01T01:00
>
> the event detail is:  {date: "2019-01-01T01:00" …}

The state is once again not set to the new format. Can anyone see what the error could be?

I am trying to render an event date to send as body to an endpoint.The user is able to input the date in the TextInput field, however before I send the event date, I want to modify its format, using moment.js inside updateEvent cb (YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss.SSS"), therefore I create a new variable

> newDate

However, the setState inside of updateEvent doesn't actually set state and keeps the value of date as it is has been set in handleEventInputChange. I have a suspicion that it could be due to setting state to the same state variable twice, inside the handleEventInputChange and handleEvent. Can anyone confirm and/or propose a solution?

```
 //... import and styles 
class EditEvent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            event: {
                date: '',
            },
        };

        this.handleEventInputChange = this.handleEventInputChange.bind(this);
        this.updateEvent = this.updateEvent.bind(this);
    }

    handleEventInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            event: {
                ...this.state.event,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }

    updateEvent() {
        const { event } = this.state;
            let newDate = moment(this.state.event.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss.SSS");

            this.setState(() => ({
                event: {
                    ...this.state.event,
                    date: newDate,
                }}))


            console.log("the new event date is ", newDate)
            console.log("the new SET event date is: ", event.date)
            console.log("the event detail is: ", event)

            this.props.updateEvent(this.props.event.id, event);
    }

    renderEvent() {
        const {
            event,
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Paper style={styles.paper}>
                    <TextField
                        name="date"
                        type="datetime-local"
                        onChange={this.handleEventInputChange}
                        value={event.date}/>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ViewContainer
                title="Update Event"
                toolbarRight={
                    <Button
                        onClick={this.updateEvent}
                    > Save
                    </Button>
                }
            >
                {this.renderEvent()}
            </ViewContainer>
        );
    }
}

//... mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps and export default connect for EditEvent
```

Comment: while setting state '[name]: value', value is not defined, this might be the problem?

Comment: @AnkushSharma Yes.

Comment: @AnkushSharma, you noticed this before me. If you post an answer, I'll delete my question so you get credit.

Comment: @ Alexander Staroselsky, no it is absolutely fine, you can keep it. i just randomly gave suggestion :-)

Comment: Not sure this is causing your issue but it should be `this.setState((state) => ({ event: { ...state.event,` etc. I.e. `setState` should take a function with `state` as your first argument and replace `...this.state.event` with `...state.event`. [Don't use `this.state` to access state inside `setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).

Comment: @ksneia https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/2404452 This should be the answer for your question. The mechanism of `setState` is still the same from 2015 according to official React document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a repost, the original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/2404452):

From React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) (at the moment of this post)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

So no, your approach will not get the updated value from `this.state` **right away after calling** `setState`, and you cannot catch the updated value in `console.log` for the same reason. According to the document, a better way is using `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.event.date !== prevState.event.date) {
    this.props.updateEvent(this.props.event.id, event);
  }
}

updateEvent() {
  const { event } = this.state;
  let newDate = moment(this.state.event.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss.SSS");

  this.setState(() => ({
      event: {
          ...this.state.event,
          date: newDate,
      }}))
}
```

If you still insist on keeping `this.props.updateEvent` inside `updateEvent` then there are 2 ways of doing it:

(1) Use `newDate` instead of `this.state.event.date`

```
updateEvent() {
  const { event } = this.state;
  let newDate = moment(this.state.event.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss.SSS");

  this.setState(() => ({
      event: {
          ...this.state.event,
          date: newDate,
      }}))

  this.props.updateEvent(this.props.event.id, {
    ...this.state.event,
    date: newDate
  });
}
```

or (2) using callback of `this.setState` to correctly get updated value

```
updateEvent() {
  const { event } = this.state;
  let newDate = moment(this.state.event.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss.SSS");

  this.setState(() => ({
      event: {
          ...this.state.event,
          date: newDate,
      }}),
      function callback() {
        this.props.updateEvent(this.props.event.id, this.state.event);
      }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code you provided, you are attempting to set `[name]: value` inside `setState()` of handler `handleEventInputChange(event)`, but you haven't set assigned a value from `event` argument to the `value` property. You'd need to add something along the lines of `const value = target.value;` before passing it to `setState()`:

```
handleEventInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value; // add this

    this.setState({
        event: {
            ...this.state.event,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}
```

You could also consider using destructuring:

```
handleEventInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const { name, value } = target;

    this.setState({
        event: {
            ...this.state.event,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}
```

**Update:** `onChange` for an `<input type="datetime-local" />` will **only** [fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209401/html-datetime-local-change-event) when all parts of the `<input type="datetime-local" />` have been filled in including day, month, year, hour, minute and AM/PM. I've creating an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xpvgdk) showing this functionality in action. Your code with the change to setting the value of `value` seems to work. If the goal is to always show the formatted date, you could consider creating another state property the holds the formatted value to avoid changing `this.state.event.date` when `updateEvent()` is triggered by the button click. This way you can avoid overwriting `this.state.event.date` constantly.

**Update 2:** Based on the comments, I'm piecing together that issue you are trying to resolve specifically is the value that is being passed to a mapped action dispatch. You could try using the `setState()` callback, 2nd argument, to call `this.props.updateEvent()`. It's key that you pass `this.event.state` into the 2nd argument of `this.props.updateEvent()` otherwise you would be passing the old/original event value. The [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xpvgdk) has been updated to reflect this.

```
updateEvent() {
    const { event } = this.state;
    let newDate = moment(this.state.event.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm:ss.SSS");

    this.setState({
      event: {
        ...this.state.event,
        date: newDate,
      }
    }, () => {
      this.props.updateEvent(this.props.event.id, this.state.event);
    });            
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thank you, @Alexander, that helped unfortunately did not resolve my problem of setting the newDate to state date

Comment: @ksenia I've creating an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xpvgdk). If you fill in **all** parts of the datetime-local input, the change event fires and the state updates which is demonstrated by `this.state.event.date` being printed/rendered. The date then get's formatted based on your moment format string after clicking the button. I had to simply the example because we don't know the rest of your application. If it's still not "working" you need to please update your question with exactly what the issue still is. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @Alexander, you creating a stackblitz sample is super helpful, but I still cannot see where the problem lies and why the state event date is not being set to newDate. I have added some logs to show for clarity, hope this helps and not confuses

Comment: @ksenia You are only expecting the formatted date to appear ONLY after the `Button`'s onClick event is clicked right? That is how you have it currently set up. Formatted date will not render/print when the input change event fires. Are you expecting the date to format with `onChange` also? Can you use something like StackBlitz or Code Sandbox to create a complete example of your functionality?

Comment: no, I did not expect the date to format onChange, however I can see that that might be necessary as the button click formats the date, but nont fast enough to send the corrected data to the updateEvent function endpoint.

Comment: I can see it in the console here: https://react-igzhmv.stackblitz.io. How do you reckon is the best way to get around this state setting issue? @Alexander

Comment: I'm confused at this point. Are you trying to ALWAYS show the formatted date? Right now, when the user completes adds a complete datetime, it renders the value coming from the input. After a button click, the date is formatted and the formatted datetime is rendered. If the user enters a new datetime, it will overwrite the formatted value as it's a single state property being manipulated. Maybe a solution would be to have two properties in state, datetime that always comes from the input and the formatted datetime. Format the datetime each time onChange happens and use that to display.

Comment: I think what I will try to do is to use async/await for the date to set to newDate before calling this.props.udateEvent()

Comment: Wait, so the issue is passing this value to a Redux action? `setState()` has a callback, 2nd argument, that you could use to execute functionality such as `updateEvent()` or `this.props.updateEvent()` after state has been updated.

Comment: exactly, this is the value to an action updateAction. Care to demo the setState() callback?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of using the callback 2nd argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182895/discussion-between-ksenia-and-alexander-staroselsky).