# Difference between input type attributes datetime and datetime-local in HTML5

Tags: html, forms, datetime

In book it is said that `datetime-local` attribute specifies a date and time input field, with no time zone.

But there is no clear reference to what `datetime` is about. I assume it specifies a date and time input field, with time zone.

I am using Linux. As such I am unable to test my code on Internet Explorer and Safari.

`datetime-local` seems to be supported only on Chrome and Opera but not on Firefox.

And `datetime` seems to be not suppoerted on any of the above mentioned browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` *used* to be supported by most browsers, but it was deprecated and removed in favour of `datetime-local`.

This is because `datetime` caused confusion - what timezone are we selecting a date and a time for? The timezone where the server is situated? The timezone where the user is situated? I believe some allowed you to pick a timezone at some point?

Anyway, **It didn't make semantic sense**, and caused a bit of confusion, so `datetime-local` was introduced to deal with this - the timezone will always be set to that of the user's location.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263515/why-is-html5-input-type-datetime-removed-from-browsers-already-supporting-it).